# how to catch previous page url so that after login i want to redirect to that page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

This is my @Url.Action it is in my layout

```
<p><a href="" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Account",new RouteValueDictionary(new { returnUrl = Request.Url}))'">Register</a> <span>/</span></p>
```

when i click on that i am getting the parameter in actionresult as `http://localhost:18841/` but i want currenturl that currenturl is as `http://localhost:18841/#/flight/search` .And i also used `returnUrl=Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath` i am getting url as `/Account/Index` what would be way to do this?

Comment: try with Request.Url.PathAndQuery

Comment: when i use Request.Url.PathAndQuery i am getting only this `/`

Comment: Are you using AngularJS? Because there is a big difference between ASP.NET MVC routing and AngularJS routing

Comment: yes i am using angularUiRouting, is it not possible to combine both things, when i ruturned the url staticly it got redirected though!

Comment: You have to create the return url in the angularjs controller. Try to set the value of @Url.Action("Index", "Account") to some data attribute for example data-url. Then bind ng-click to the anchor and in the JS get the value of the data-url and add '?returnUrl' = $window.location.origin + $window.location.pathname

Comment: Yes Thanks i will try this now, but can't we get the previous url purely by mvc?

Comment: I think you cannot take the previous url with pure mvc